# How can I order an array by date and then extract only portions based on top%?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, array

I have a list of email records that I need to order by recency, there is a field in the array called 'last_opened', and I then need to extract certain amounts only. e.g.

group a - 1.6% (322 records)
group b - 3.2% (....and so forth for 5 groups.)
I'm struggling to order the list and create the groups based on a % amount. <

```
br><br>

<b>The current output looks like:</b><br><br>
name:"Email" <br>
value:"1621domain@yahoo.com" <br>
name:"Opt_in" 
value:"Y" 
name:"Contact_ID" 
value:"" 
name:"Verified" 
value:"Y" 
name:"Last_opened" 
value:"6/25/2017 12:00:00 AM" 
name:"Last_sent" 
value:"6/22/2017 12:00:00 AM" 
name:"Rank" 
value:"1" 
<br><Br>
full code I'm using is below: <br>
<script runat="server"><br> 
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");<br>  
// create data extension definition<br> <br>    
var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");<br> 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", <br>  "DataExtensionObject[1_Master_Data]");<br>  
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Email");<br>    
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Opt_in");<br>   
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Contact_ID");<br>   
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Verified");<br> 
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Last_opened");<br>  
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Last_sent");<br>    
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Rank");<br> 
// retrieve results and look-through to assign property fields to variables.<br>    <br>    
do { 
    var results = [0,0];<br>    
    var rows = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, results);  <br>   
    var runstatus = results[0];<br> 
    var requestId = results[1];<br>  
    <br>    
    for (var i in rows) {<br>   
      var output = rows[i];<br> 
      var properties = output["Properties"];    <br>       
     // Write( Stringify(properties) + " <br/>");

       for (var j in properties) {   <br>       
       var name = properties[j]["Name"];<br>    
       var value = properties[j]["Value"]; <br> 
       Write("name:" + Stringify(name) + " <br/>");
       Write("value:" + Stringify(value) + " <br/>");                         
    } 
}     
rr.ContinueRequest = requestId;     <br>                    
} while (runstatus == "MoreDataAvailable")<br><Br
</script>
```

Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RetrieveRequest does not support OrderBy function, you have to retrieve all records store them in a variable, create a new array, loop through each record in RetreiveRequest return objects, insert into new array depend on the last_opened compare to existing objects in the new array. once you have completed the looping.You should have the new array with objects sorted by last_opened, then select group percentage portion.

Comment: wonderful, that flow simplified matters and did the job nicely!